# ANTLR semantic predicate - consume only part of the match

Tags: antlr4

I need to handle this sequences: <1>, <1-2>, <3-5 /0.5/>. 
In ANTLR v3 I used these rules:

```
LPOINTY : ('<' REPEAT (PROBABILITY)? '>') => '<' // will consume only '<' 
repeatOperator : LPOINTY_OR_ABNF_URI (XML_NM_TOKEN (weightOrProbability'>')?
```

In ANTLR v4, there is not allowed this opertor "=>", so I wrote this like that:

```
LPOINTY_OR_ABNF_URI // will return only digit, ex: 1, 1-2, 3-5 
: '<' REPEAT '>' { setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length() - 1)); }
| '<' REPEAT WS+ { setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length())); }
; 

repeatOperator
:  LPOINTY_OR_ABNF_URI (WEIGHT_OR_PROBABILITY)? SHARP_BRACKET_RIGHT? 
;
```

where tokens:

- XML_NM_TOKEN - it match content of '<..>'
- weightOrProbability and WEIGHT_OR_PROBABILITY - it match /0.5/
- PROBABILITY - it match /0.5/
- WS - it match white spaces
- SHARP_BRACKET_RIGHT - it matches '>'

Is there better way to this ? I would like to use look ahead functionality and consume only the first charcter, like in old version. Is there a way do this ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
 REPEAT_OP1
 : '<' REPEAT '>'    { setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length()-1)); }
 ;             

 REPEAT_OP2
 :   '<' REPEAT      { setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length())); }       
 ;

repeatOperator
: REPEAT_OP1 
| REPEAT_OP2 WEIGHT_OR_PROBABILITY? SHARP_BRACKET_RIGHT 
| REPEAT_OP2 WEIGHT_OR_PROBABILITY? {notifyErrorListeners("Missing closing '>'!");}
;
```